# Irrationality measure of a polynomial in $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, pi, irrationality-measure

Consider a number $x$ with known irrationality measure $r$ (for example $\pi$ with $7<r<8$). Is there anything we can say about the irrationality measure of a polynomial 
\begin{align}
p=p(x)=\sum_{n\in N}c_nx^n
\end{align} where $N\subset\mathbb{N}$ is some finite index set and the coefficients $c_n$ are rational (or even $c_n=1$ for all $n$, if that makes things easier)? Will it be finite? Does it depend on $N$?

I don't know much about number theory, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that it's know whatever the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $>7$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I'm not really sure what you mean though: it is known that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is 7.6063... following Salikhov's 2008 result.

Comment: No, that's the upper bound of the irrationality measure of $\pi$, not the measure itself.

Comment: Ah yes of course, I'm sorry! But still, knowing that it is finite, is there anything we can say about the irrationality measure of the polynomial $p(\pi)$?

Comment: The irrationality measure of $\pi$ is almost certainly $2$.

Comment: And the same is likely to be true for all nonconstant rational polynomials of $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume the coefficients are integers. 
If $|x - p/q| < c/q^\alpha$, then $|f(x) - f(p/q)| \le Kc |x - p/q| < Kc/q^\alpha$ where $K$ is an upper bound for $|f'|$ in a neighbourhood of $x$.  Since $f(p/q)$ has denominator $\le q^d$ where $f$ has degree $d$, we find that the irrationality measure of $f(x)$ is at least $r/d$.